# How to show AJAX response data inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

I am using Laravel framework. I get stuck on this. I get data successfully. But, when I want to display the data, it displays me data in array form. Can anyone help me how to display the Listing. I have one layout inside `div`

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9  col-xs-12" id="ajaxListings">
    @include('layouts.publicLayout.get-listings')// here i have implemented layout
</div>
```

and

```
function filteredlistings(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'search-listings',
            data:{
                'service_name':title,
                'location':location
            },
            type:"get",
            success:function(allData)
            {
                $("#ajaxListings").html(allData);
            },
            error: function()
            {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    }
```

And here is my function :

```
public function search_listings(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax()){
        $data = $_GET;
        $users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('business_services', 'users.id', '=', 'business_services.user_id')
        ->join('listings','users.id', '=', 'listings.user_id')
        ->select('users.id', 'business_services.name', 'business_services.list_id','listings.location')
        ->where(['business_services.name'=>$data['service_name'],'users.service_name'=>"Seller"])
        ->where('listings.location','like','%'.$data['location'].'%')
        ->get();
        $users = json_decode(json_encode($users),true);
        foreach($users as $alluser){
            $ids[] = $alluser['id']; 
        }
        $allData="";
        if(!empty($ids)){
                $allData = User::with('listings')->whereIn('id',$ids)->get();
                $allData = json_decode(json_encode($allData),true);
        }
        $title = "Nails";
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($allData); die;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like your server is returning the information as an array.  You probably need to iterate through the response and build your html.

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: I want to show Html data in the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iguess that you want to return the layout + the data, so you could use :

```
return view('layouts.publicLayout.get-listings',compact('allData'));
```

Instead of :

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($allData); die;
```

You could access your data inside the layout using `$allData`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this:

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($allData); die;
```

Instead of `print_r`, return the data as JSON so that it can be parsed by jQuery:

```
return response()->json($allData);
```

Then in your jQuery success function you can iterate over the data

```
success:function(allData)
{
    // simple example showing the firstnames
    var example = '';
    $.each(allData, function(){
       example += ', ' + this.firstname;
    });
    $("#ajaxListings").text(example);
},
```

Comment: its displays only my name how to display my html data